# TypeError: cannot convert int to str implicitely

Tags: python, typeerror

Im having trouble fixing this code can someone help me I don't know how to fix the 'sale' function help please and thank you

```
def main():
    #store introduction
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print("Welcome to the Movie Store!")
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

    #user input on budget
    budget = (input("What is your budget?"))
    print("Your budget is " + budget + "$.")
    
    # declaring variables
    sale = (200 - int(budget))
    
    # selection statements to determine subtotal
    if (200 > int(budget)):
        print("If you spend $" + sale + " you'll qualify for a gift!")
    else:
        print("You qualify for a free gift!")
    print("We recommend our all time best seller Marvels Black Panther!")

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable sale is an integer, which must be converted to a string before your print statement will work.

Do this

```
if (200 > int(budget)):
    print("If you spend $" + str(sale) + " you'll qualify for a gift!")
else:
    print("You qualify for a free gift!")
```

The str() function converts the sale variable to a string so it can be joined with the + operators and printed to console.

Answer (score 6):

Use f-strings for variable substitution (there are also many many other ways):

```
print(f"Your budget is {budget}$.")
print(f"If you spend ${sale} you'll qualify for a gift!")
```

In your code currently, you are trying to add the string "Your budget is" to the integer `budget`, and python doesn't know how to do that. An alternative is to cast the variable to a string explicitly:

```
print("Your budget is " + str(budget) + "$.")
```

Or use formatting:

```
print("Your budget is %s$." % (budget,))
```